# Knitr and tikzDevice not working together with article options

Tags: font-size, knitr, tikz

I have a problem with `knitr` and `tikzDevice`, like someone before me. (See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/106057/tikzdevice-is-not-getting-sizes-right-knitr/106595#106595 .) He used `dev.args` to get rid of this error, but if I run this code through `knitr` (with `rstudio`), the fontsize is still messed up. `dev.args=list(pointsize=12)` doesn't work for me. The only thing that works, is to remove `a4paper,12pt`. Any ideas on what I did do wrong?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrartcl}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
<<dev='tikz', dev.args=list(pointsize=12)>>=
x<-1
plot(x)
@
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turns out to be a bug of `tikzDevice` package, which has been [reported long time ago](https://github.com/Sharpie/RTikZDevice/pull/61) (but still not fixed). The problem is the regular expression used to detect the pointsize was wrong (they should have used `pt` instead of `[pt]`):

```
> tikzDevice:::getDocumentPointsize
function (docString) 
{
    psLocation <- regexpr("\\d+[pt]", docString, ignore.case = T, 
        perl = T)
    if (psLocation == -1) {
        return(NA)
    }
    else {
        pointsize <- substr(docString, psLocation, psLocation + 
            attr(psLocation, "match.length") - 2)
        return(as.numeric(pointsize))
    }
}
```

There are a number of ways to fix this problem. The best way is to fix it in `tikzDevice`, of course. Before that happens, you can use this simple trick:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
```

That is, switch `12pt` with `a4paper` so that `12` instead of `4` can be detected.